# Add class attribute on click in code behind to Master Page body tag - vb.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

When the user clicks to open a popup I want to add a class to the body HTML tag to prevent scrolling of the background. The popup resides in a content page. I've added runat server to my body tag on my main.Master page:

```
<body runat="server" id="MasterPageBodyTag">
```

In the code behind of my content page I have the following:

```
Protected Sub lnkShowNotes_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnkShowNotes.Click 
    mvwNotes.SetActiveView(vwNoteList) 
    mdlNotesPopup.Show() 

    Dim body As HtmlControl = Master.FindControl("MasterPageBodyTag") 
    body.Attributes.Add("class", "cssBodyClass") 
End Sub
```

When I debug I can see in the results view that the class is there in the attributes, however on the page the class is not getting added to the body element.

Comment: What is in the popup and how is it opened? Your above code works and will add a class to the body (after PostBack), but that does not mean it will be present in the popup.

Comment: The popup opens on a click, this function comes from the code behind (updated question to include this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the popup is loaded with Ajax. Therefore there will be no full PostBack and thus the body class does not change. You need to set the bodyclass with JavaScript or jQuery, either in the frontent or in the backend.

In the backend you can do this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType, "setBodyClass", "$('#MasterPageBodyTag').attr('class', 'cssBodyClass');", true)
```

Comment: This is a great start, but your line of code actually has a couple of areas it can be improved:

1. Page.GetType is a function, not a property
2. Calling jQuery's AddClass is much better than overwriting the class attribute.

Here's the updated code:

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "setBodyClass", "$('body').addClass('cssBodyClass');", true);`